# How to record screen while using bluetooth headphones with both mic and playback audio in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, screen-recording

I am building an app in which I am attending meeting and I am using library [HBRecorder](https://github.com/HBiSoft/HBRecorder)
to record screen, I am able to record both audio and video when using phone's speaker and wired headphones, but problem comes when I use bluetooth headphones, while using bluetooth headphones I am able to record my voice but the other person voice is not getting recorded who is in meeting with me.

Any help appreciated

I tried all possible audio input sources for HBRecorder, like DEFAULT, MIC, and CAMCORDER but none worked for me using bluetooth headphones

```
hbRecorder!!.setAudioSource("CAMCORDER")
```